# Handling temporary files in Bash

Tags: bash, file, parent-child

I need to copy and execute a bash script from within a parent bash script, when the job is done (and if it fails) I need the parent script to remove the child script file that it copied.

Here's the code snippet that I'm working on:

```
if [ -e $repo_path/install ]; then
  cp $repo_path/install $install_path
  exec $install_path/install
  rm $install_path/install
fi
```

This fails for some reason, it seems to exit altogether when the child process ends. 
Is it correct to use `exec` is this example?

Comment: The way to mark a question as "solved" is to accept an answer, not change the title. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

`exec` replaces your current process, so the statements after that will never be reached.

You may replace `exec` with `sh` or `bash`, or just remove it if the child script is executable.

See also: [The Bash Reference Manual for exec](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec)